# C++ : Trying to create a function that add 1 to an integer when someone say "yes" in the console

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So i'm trying to create a function that add 1 to an integer everytime someone respond yes, that's my code :

```
#include "yesToNumber.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int yesToNumber(string yes, int numberOfYes)
{
    if ("yes"=="yes")
    {
        numberOfYes++;
        yes = "";
    }
}
```

But i don't know where to put the function in my main code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "yesToNumber.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string agree, dontAgree;

    cout<<"The question is : Do you have a computer ? Please answer with yes or no."<<endl;
    cout<<"You have a computer."<<endl;
    cin>>agree;
    cout<<"You don't have a computer."<<endl;
    cin>>dontAgree;

    cout<<"number of people who said yes : "<<agree<<" / number of people who said no"<<dontAgree<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

So i'm looking for help and some tips !

Comment: `if ("yes"=="yes")`??

Comment: This program is a classic case of one in which you should read it and try to convince yourself of why it will do what you're wanting it to do (because it really looks like it doesn't). Break it down into small tasks, perhaps line by line.

Comment: Just change to `if (yes=="yes")`. Closing voting as trivial question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The actual question is where to put the (non-working) function into the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here:

```
int main()
{
    int numberOfYes = 0;

    for(int number_of_people = 10, people_asked = 0; people_asked < number_of_people; people_asked++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Do you have a computer?";
        std::string answer;
        std::cin >> answer;
        yesToNumber(answer, numberOfYes);
    }

    std::cout << numberOfYes;
    return 0;
}
```

The for loop asks if you have a computer, gets your answer, then calls your function which deals with that information.

There are some problems with your function though.

For starters the second parameter of `yesToNumber` should be a reference. That way, when you change it in the function it is changing the variable that is outside the function and not a copy of it. Also, if you don't want this function to return anything, then just make the return type void `void yesToNumber(string yes, int &numberOfYes)` Also, right now you are comparing the value of a pointer to a string to the value of another pointer to a string. I don't think that is what you want to do. I think you want to compare the contents of the strings. Well thankfully `std::string` comes with a function that does just that, and it can be accessed with a simple `==`. What you want to do is `if(yes == "yes")`. Finally, you don't need `yes = "";` at the end of your function because `std::cin` overwrites the string regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Well. First you will need a for-loop that will run until there are no people left. Perhaps 10 people are asking, make it run 10 times.

In your function, there is a problem.

```
if ("yes"=="yes")// this is always true. Remove the " " around the first yes
if (yes == "yes") // This checks if what the user entered is equal to yes.
```

Then you can call it inside your for-loop. Also don't forget that the 
numberOfYes has to be sent in by reference. Otherwise you would be changing a copy of numberOfYes and not the original variable.

```
yesToNumber(string yes, int& numberOfYes) // added & after int
```

Small sample:

```
std::string answer;
int numberOfYes = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cin >> answer;
    yesToNumber(answer, numberOfYes ); // Calling the function 
}
```